# How to enable submit button if at least two checkboxes are checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the help of answers I found here, I try to disable submit button and send an alert message when clicked on it until there's not at least 2 checkboxes checked.

What I am doing wrong ?

```
var selected = $('#frmCompare :checkbox:checked').length;

function verifCompare() {
    if (selected >= 2) {
        //good
        $('#frmCompare').submit();
    } else {
        //bad
        alert('Veuillez selectionner au moins 2 produits à comparer...');
        return false
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnCompare').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#frmCompare :checkbox').change(function () {
        //alert(selected);
        if (selected >= 2) {
            $('#btnCompare').attr('enabled');
        }
    });
});
```

At this point, only alert message works.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrSo/3PKY9/)**

EDIT : added fiddle

Comment: please show HTML.  What kind of control is `#frmCompare` and `#btnCompare`?

Comment: @Hogan : `#frmCompare` is the name of my form, `#btnCompare` the submit button

Comment: Fiddle added to help me to see what's happens ?

Comment: I don't believe the fiddle is the same as your code since the fiddle does not show the alert message working and you claim that works with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `enabled` attribute in HTML.

```
$('#btnCompare').prop('disabled', selected < 2);
```

You also need to recalculate the value of `selected` at every `change`, you can't just go with what it was set to at page load.

Comment: You only implemented the code change in your fiddle. You didn't move the evaluation of `select` into the `onchange` event. In your code, the value of `select` will always be whatever it was when the page loaded. [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7yL2/)

Answer (score 1):

You initialize the count of checked checkboxes just once, when your script is first parsed. The count will not be recomputed later. This line:

```
var selected = $('#frmCompare :checkbox:checked').length;
```

should be inside the verification function, not outside.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code as

```
$('#frmCompare :checkbox').change(function(){

  //update selected variable
  selected = $('#frmCompare :checkbox:checked').length

  if (selected >= 2) {
     $('#btnCompare').attr('enabled');
  }
});
```